# how to get angular 6 UI elements in cypress without class name and id or name attribute

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, cypress

How to get angular 6 UI elements in cypress without class name and id or name attribute with having only `ngModel` for input and for button only having method call.

Example:
How can I get the below elements in cypress?

1)   `<ion-input type="email" placeholder="test text field"></ion-input>`

2)   `<ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" placeholder="test text field name"></ion-input>`

3)   `<ion-segment-button value="Actions" (click)="callMethod()">Click Me</ion-segment-button>`

Answer (score 1):

You can access by placeholder:

```
cy.get('ion-input[placeholder=placeholderText]')
```

Or as recommended in the **cypress** docs: just add **data-cy="yourKey"** attribute to your element. And then it can be accessed by:

```
cy.get('[data-cy=yourKey]'))
```

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Selecting-Elements